# Where in Shiraz, Iran can I find "The Pause"?

Tags: where-on-earth, iran, architecture, locate-this

I'm looking for (the exact location of) this project:
http://iranian-architect.ir/project-0214

[image]

The architect is Amir Hossein Ashari. It's somewhere in the city of Shiraz, Iran and is built in 2017.

Answer (score 7):

The article you link to says it's near here (Afif Abad Garden in Shiraz):

https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Afif+Abad+Garden/@29.6223665,52.495758,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3fb21248322b2065:0x37b690290b99c0d7!8m2!3d29.6223619!4d52.4979467?hl=en

Comment: Also found _Afif Abad Garden_ reference at [www.archdaily.com](https://www.archdaily.com/877555/this-architectural-installation-reconnects-with-the-senses-through-suspended-bricks).

Comment: Meanwhile I found this [article](http://www.archilovers.com/projects/213292/the-pause.html) pointing to a different location...

Comment: @user1073075: Where do you see this reference. The article you link to says "...near one of the most important historic gardens “Afif Abad Garden” in Shiraz..."

Comment: The map left site on this [page](http://www.archilovers.com/projects/213292/the-pause.html) shows a different location (click it and zoom) - could be wrong of course...

Comment: I saw that, indeed. I figured the map just points to 'Shiraz'. The article in question also mentions the same gardens.

Comment: [This image](http://iranian-architect.ir/project-0214/project-0214_02) on the page linked in the OP, which was presumably produced by the architects, also implies that it's in Afif Abad Garden.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Your point is taken.

Answer (score 6):

It is at [this exact location](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/29%C2%B037'26.0%22N+52%C2%B029'59.9%22E/@29.623898,52.4993055,224m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d29.6238985!4d52.4999576), inside Afif Abad Gardens, between the end of Afif Abad St and the military museum. It is tricky to spot in Satellite view, but [this planning diagram](http://iranian-architect.ir/wp-content/uploads/project-0214_02.jpg) from your article points to a a structure of pathways that is clearly visible, and The Pause can be seen as a grey square close to its proposed location in the diagram.

Comment: It looks like it's no longer there...